# Problem with variable initialization with empty object

Tags: typescript

I have a generic class, which gets some interface as type parameter called `DataType`. I know that all fields of passed interface are optional (but don't know how to inform **ts** about this) so I want to initialize private field `data` with empty object, because in the beginning it is always empty but can be filled with some values

```
class Basic<DataType extends {}> {
  private data: DataType = {} // this line throws ts2322 error
}

class Man extends Basic<{ firstName?: string, age?: number }> {}
class Animal extends Basic<{ name?: string, isPet?:boolean }> {}
```

but get an error **ts2322**

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.   '{}' is assignable
> to the constraint of type 'DataType', but 'DataType' could be
> instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'

Can this problem be solved?

Comment: You should take a look at TypeScript's Utility Types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Why do you think you need to initialize `data` inside `Basic`? (Hint: you don't)

Comment: There are [over 1000 questions which mention TS2322](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ts2322). Please at least look through a couple and say how the answers presented for them don't fit your question.

Comment: @Dai, where i should initialize a class member? Outside of class? I've heard that typescript is different from javascript but didn't think that so far

Comment: Please read [ask]. The first section is titled "Search, and research..." I don't believe it is arrogant to ask people to do some research and try to answer their own questions before asking others to do the same. See also the FAQ [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think that is the answer to this specific question. What OP is ultimately looking for is an object type with all optional properties.

Comment: @ExplosionPills which I'm sure has been answered before...

Comment: @Dai, actually thanks a lot for link to utility-types page, it helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific issue is saying that while DataType fulfills `{}`, the reverse may not be true since you can implement the generic as something that fits the constraint of `{}` (an object), but is of a different type. For example, if you had `DataType` be of type `{ firstName: string }`, you would not be able to assign `{}` to it. TypeScript does this for type safety... there is no way to know ahead of time whether the generic type will be incompatible with `{}`.

It appears that what you actually want is for `data` not to be of `DataType`, but to be compatible with `DataType` but with all properties optional. This can be achieved with the [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) type:

```
private data: Partial<Datatype> = {};
```

Comment: You know you can edit your answers, right? There's no need to delete the answer and write a whole new one...

Comment: Interesting, thanks, but is there any way to check may be using js code that all properties of DataType has question mark, which means they are optional?

Comment: @DmitryReutov optional properties are strictly related to types / TypeScript. In JavaScript, all properties are optional. Note that because of how `Partial` works, it doesn't matter whether any of the properties you declare for `DataType` are optional or not. `Partial` will make them optional.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, Okay, i will research more abot Partial to understand if it is solution or better just assign as `data = {} as DataType`

Comment: @DmitryReutov these are different approaches; if you cast, then TypeScript will not warn you if the properties are not optional. For example, `data.property` could be undefined, so `data.property.subproperty` would be a runtime error. The `Partial` approach will warn you that `data.property` is possibly undefined during type checking.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, Ok, but my basic class doesn't know subproperties so it will return just properties to child class, which knows subproperties. Thanks a lot, very useful.